# SharePoint AD FS Relying Trust Endpoint issues

Tags: authentication, adfs, relying-party-trust

**************EDIT****************

Muliple endpoints in the same relying trust is possible if the `SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer` has `UseWReplyParameter` enabled.  This should help out with SharePoint Hosted Apps.

```
$tit = Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer fs.contoso.com
$tit.UseWReplyParameter = $true
$tit.Update()
```

Please see the following blog:
[SharePoint and ADFS with SharePoint Hosted apps](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-with-saml-claims-and-sharepoint-hosted-apps)

**************EDIT****************

So I have configured an AD FS Relying Trust with multiple endpoints.  Regardless of which endpoint I am coming from, AD FS redirects to the default endpoint.  For example if someone is viewing a page within https://sp2013dev.com and clicks on their mysite, they are navigated back to https://sp2013dev.com.  If I switch the endpoint such that MySites.sp2013dev.com is the default endpoint, users that browse to sp2013dev.com will instead be brought to the MySite Host.

[image: AD FS Endpoints]

******EDIT********

I configured my `ProviderRealms` for the `TrustedIdentityTokenIssuer` as follows
[image: TrustedIdentityTokenIssuer ProviderRealms]

I also ensured that the Relying party identifiers included the URNs.

[image: ADFS Relying Party Identifier URNs]

******EDIT********

I tried configuring a wildcard endpoint but received an error stating that wildcard endpoints are not supported for the default endpoint.

Is there a way to configure separate endpoints for one Relying Party Trust or do I have to configure multiples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple endpoints in the same relying trust is possible if the SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer has UseWReplyParameter enabled. This should help out with SharePoint Hosted Apps.

```
$tit = Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer fs.contoso.com
$tit.UseWReplyParameter = $true
$tit.Update()
```

Please see the following blog: [SharePoint and ADFS with SharePoint Hosted apps](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-with-saml-claims-and-sharepoint-hosted-apps)

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the Seprate end point for each Web application.

```
 $ap1 = Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer -identity "Adfs name"
$uri = new-object System.Uri("url of webapp/")
$ap1.ProviderRealms.Add($uri, "urn:sharepoint:MySite")
$ap1.Update()
```

Comment: That has been configured and I did an iisreset and cleared my cache.  Is there something I need to do to get it to stick?

Comment: if you run this command $ap1.ProviderRealms can you see all your web apps

Comment: Yes.  Each are configured for the same urn but with a different URL.  Is that an issue?

Comment: that is problem, URN should be different for each web app

Comment: Thanks!  I added the realms to the Relying Trust, and removed the provider realms and re-added with the correct urn information.  I executed an iisreset  to be sure.  It is still redirecting to the default endpoint.

Comment: did you create one package for all relying parties? I had issue in past where it is doing same thing, in my case URN mismatch with web application name...in Sharepoint name of web application is Mysite and in URN i mentioned MySite...case mismatch.

Comment: I don't think I have a mismatch.  I added screenshots of the potential issue points.

Comment: try to create separate relying party registration for each url at adfs?